# Getting Unknown column 'userName' in 'field list' while hitting a insert mysql query in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have been getting a **Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'** error each time I try to insert data into my user table.I do not understand what I am doing wrong.Kindly help.

This is the query I used to create the user table.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    userId Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    mobileNumber char(10) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    birth_date Date,
    companyAddress varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
   createdTime time
);
```

This is the insert query string which I am using

```
const query= `INSERT INTO users (username,email,mobileNumber,birth_date,companyAddress,createdTime) VALUES ('${username}','${email}','${mobileNumber}','${birth_date}','${companyAddress}','${createdTime}')`;
```

On hitting the post request from POSTMAN,I am getting the following error.

```
{
"status": 400,
"message": "Unable to register",
"error": {
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'",
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "INSERT INTO users (username,email,mobileNumber,birth_date,companyAddress,createdTime) VALUES ('Shijil','abc@yahoo.co.in','1234567890','15/01/1992','addr text','1526617807260')"
   }
}
```

Please help me resolve this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check for accidental non-printable character in either the create table or in the insert statement. Also check if you are trying to insert into the wrong database or host.

Answer (score -1):

You are using ES6 string interpolation and also using `'`. I think it is the reason for the error. Rewrite your query as like this one. It may solve your problem

```
const query= `INSERT INTO users (username,email,mobileNumber,birth_date,companyAddress,createdTime) VALUES (${username},${email},${mobileNumber},${birth_date},${companyAddress},${createdTime})`;
```